# join multiple table with condition according to column value in first table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, codeigniter-3

Hi I have eight tables and I have to get data from these all tables. Table structure is like as :

```
event_info
id | event_id | event_types | animal_type

human_victim_info
id | event_id | victim_full_name | address

livestock_destruction_info
id | event_id | owner_name | owner_address

crop_destruction_info
id | event_id | crop_land_type

proprty_destruction_info
id | event_id | property_type | cost

other_destruction_info
id | event_id | description

additional_info
id | event_id | images | feedback

wild_animal_info 
id | event_id | number | location_from | location_to
```

I have used join as :

```
SELECT e.*
     , wa.*
     , hv.*
     , lv.*
     , c.*
     , p.*
     , o.*
     , a.*
     , e.id as eId
     , e.event_id as eventId 
  FROM event_info e
  LEFT 
  JOIN wild_animal_info wa 
    ON wa.event_id = e.event_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN human_victim_info hv 
    ON hv.event_id = e.event_id
   AND e.event_types LIKE '%1%'
  LEFT 
  JOIN livestock_destruction_info lv 
    ON lv.event_id = e.event_id 
   AND e.event_types LIKE '%2%'
  LEFT 
  JOIN crop_destruction_info c 
    ON c.event_id = e.event_id 
   AND e.event_types LIKE '%3%'
  LEFT 
  JOIN proprty_destruction_info p 
    ON p.event_id = e.event_id 
   AND e.event_types LIKE '%4%' 
  LEFT 
  JOIN other_destruction_info o 
    ON o.event_id = e.event_id 
   AND e.event_types LIKE '%5%'
  LEFT 
  JOIN additional_info a 
    ON a.event_id = e.event_id 
 WHERE e.event_id LIKE '%0026-%';
```

where I want to join human_victim_info table only if event_types in event_info table contains 1, similarly join livestock_destruction_info only if event_types in event_info table contains 2, similarly join crop_destruction_info only if event_types in event_info table contains 3 and so on upto other_destruction info. But I have to always join wild_animal_info and additional_info_table. I have event_id on each table. How could I do this?

Comment: The problem stems from poor design. If you're querying a table on terms LIKE '%3%', etc., then things have gone very wrong somewhere.

Comment: Ohh..How could I modify table design to easily get the desired output?

Comment: by having a separate table of event_types, storing the event and the type in a normalised manner.

Comment: IMHO this is better left to some PHP code, joining all of those tables isn't needed, simply fetch the event and then pick up the corresponding sub tables as indicated by the event type.

Comment: @NigelRen that would scale even less if data from all 8 tabels need to be fetched that O(n^8)

Comment: @e4c5 it's not always about performance - especially when the alternative is to potentially link to 8 tables when data is only required from 2.  Maintainable code has much more mileage unless performance has proved to be a problem.

Comment: The table structure already shows a totally unmaintainable system. SO lets at least worry about the performance shall we?